# IndexError - Appending to a list twice

Tags: python, append, index-error

I am getting an error for my code below. The 3rd index in my file is the times for a web server log. I want to append it to the empty list.
The second value I try to append always gets this error, regardless of what information is used. Any suggestions to fix this?
Code:

```
nasa = open('NASA_access_log_Jul95')
import statistics

dns = []
loginTime = []

for lineOne in nasa:
    split_data = lineOne.split(" ")
    dns.append(split_data[0])
    loginTime.append(split_data[3])

freq = statistics.mode(dns)
least = min(dns)

print(freq)
print(loginTime)
```

**- Exact Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/technomancer/PycharmProjects/Akhters_DATA_Parsing/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    loginTime.append(split_data[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**- Sample Lines for Nasa Text File**

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message as you get it. Likely there is no 4th item in the split line?

Comment: Please copy paste a sample line from the file 'NASA_access_log_Jul95'.

Comment: " The second value I try to append always gets this error, regardless of what information is used." Gets *what* error? What happened when you tried to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code? For example, *when the error occurs*, what is the value of `split_data`? How many elements does it have? Does it make sense to use `0` and `3` as indices into that? Why?

Comment: Please do not use the comment section to add additional information to your question. Instead, click the `Edit` link and edit your post. Format file contents and error tracebacks as you would format code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this based on your data. Your input has couple of new line characters at the beginning and end. If you want to include that as well, you may want to check `if len(split_data) > 1` before appending.

```py
nasa = open('NASA_access_log_Jul95')
import statistics

dns = []
loginTime = []

for line in nasa.read().split("\n"):
     split_data = line.split(" ")
     if len(split_data) > 1:
         dns.append(split_data[0])
         loginTime.append(split_data[3])

freq = statistics.mode(dns)
least = min(dns)

print(freq)
print(loginTime)
```

Comment: This worked, Thank you!